# How to allow specific user to write to Firebase

Tags: firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I am trying to allow specific user to write to Firebase. The issue is that I am getting error:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "events": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth.uid = 'google:xxxxxxxx..xx'"
    }
  }
}
```

the error that I am getting :

> 6:18: Rule expressions may not contain assignments.

Comment: A single `=` is an assignment. You'll want to use `==` or `===` (they're equivalent in database security rules).

Comment: please make it post that I can do that this is the solution

Comment: Good to hear that it solved your problem. Given that developers who may make this same mistake are not likely to find your question, I instead voted to close it as a "typo".